# Criação de form as vezes fica atrás form principal

Tags: c#, winforms

Pessoa,

Estou criando meus forms filhos da seguinte maneira.

```
BuscaUsuario _chld = new BuscaUsuario();
_chld.ShowDialog();
_chld.Dispose();
```

Acontece que se o usuário aperta alt+tab ou por exemplo se estou debugando e vai para IDE e depois volto para a aplicação o form filho fica sempre atrás do form pai.

Existe uma maneira que na criação do form obrigue ele a sempre ficar por cima?

Comment: você pode utilizar a propriedade `TopMost` do form para isso, dê uma olhada aqui se ela te satisfaz: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx. lembrando que ela fará com que a tela sempre esteja a frente, mesmo com alt tab até aonde me recordo.

Comment: Marciano, testei a propriedade mas não é bem isso que eu queria, como você falou o form fica em cima de tudo inclusive de outras janelas que não tem nada a ver com o sistema.

Comment: Tentei reproduzir esse comportamento com o alt+tab ou ainda o debug mas não consegui. Ao chamar o form filho com o ShowDialog, ele normalmente receberá o foco e sempre estará a frente do form que o chamou. Se do seu exemplo puder postar o código dos arquivos Designer.cs ajudará.

Comment: Ismael, tente fazer assim para simular. Cria 3 forms MainForm, depois um filho e depois um outro form para pesquisa por exemplo. Quando apertar ALT+TAB Se o foco for para o 2 form não vou conseguir mexer no form ativo que seria o form de Pesquisa. Existe uma maneira de deixar travado e sempre que requisitar foco no form ele sempre mandar o foco para o ultimo form aberto? Obrigado @ismael